# INSERT query executes but the table is empty using MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I wrote a Python script that executes some queries as follows:

```
cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb;')

table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS links (
             keyword VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
             url VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)"""

cur.execute(table)
```

From the MySQL shell I see that there's nothing wrong:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| testdb             |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)


mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_testdb   |
+--------------------+
| links              |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The issue is an `INSERT` query that takes two arguments:

```
cur3.execute("INSERT INTO links(keyword,url) VALUES(%s,%s);",(sys.argv[1],link))
```

Checking in MySQL there is something wrong:

```
mysql> SELECT * from links;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is the table empty after executing the `INSERT` query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure commit your change using [`Connection.commit`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit):

```
cur3.execute("INSERT INTO links(keyword, url) VALUES(%s, %s)", (sys.argv[1], link))
connection_object.commit()
```

According to [MySQLdb FAQ - My data disappeared! (or won't go away!)](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away):

> Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default, as
>   required by the DB-API standard ([PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)). If you are using InnoDB
>   tables or some other type of transactional table type, you'll need to
>   do `connection.commit()` before closing the connection, or else none of
>   your changes will be written to the database.
>
> Conversely, you can also use `connection.rollback()` to throw away any
>   changes you've made since the last commit.
>
> Important note: Some SQL statements -- specifically DDL statements
>   like `CREATE TABLE` -- are non-transactional, so they can't be rolled
>   back, and they cause pending transactions to commit.

Comment: You can also auto-commit with `connection_object.autocommit()` after defining your `connection_object`

Comment: @xnx, Thank you for your comment. But that's not a part of [**DB API 2**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: Another option, implemented by MySQLdb but not specified in the API, is to use a context manager to perform transactions, e.g.: `with connection as cursor: cursor.execute(query)` will commit at the end of the `with` block.